# How do you align mathematical text?

Tags: math-mode, align

Is there a way to align the text as the image shows?

[image]

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=]
 



 \item $\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\Pi^n\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=$\begin{cases}1 $ SSE $ \mathscr{I}(\langle \alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \rangle) \in  \mathscr{I}(\Pi^n)
 \\
 0 $ nei restanti casi$
    

 \end{cases}
 
 \item $\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\lnot \varphi) =$\begin{cases} 1 $ SSE $ \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi)=0
\\

0 $ nei casi restanti$
    
\end{cases}

 \item  $\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi \land \psi) =$\begin{cases} 1 $ SSE $ \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi)=1 $ e $ \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\psi)=1
\\

0 $ nei casi restanti$

    
\end{cases} \end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package. In your case,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\Pi^n\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_n) &=
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{SSE~}\mathscr{I}(\langle \alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_n \rangle) \in  \mathscr{I}(\Pi^n) \\
            0 & \text{nei restanti casi}
        \end{cases} \\
        \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\lnot \varphi) &=
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{SSE~}\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi)=0 \\
            0 & \text{nei casi restanti}
        \end{cases} \\
        \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi \land \psi) &=
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{SSE~}\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi) = 1 \text{ e } \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\psi)=1 \\
            0 & \text{nei casi restanti}
        \end{cases}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

By the way, `align` produces numbered equations, while `align*` produces unnumbered equations. Also, `&` is where the anchor points of alignment. (Not sure if I called them correctly.)

---

For the `align*` environment, the output is

[image]

Please comment if you have any questions.

---

Update: I forgot to mention that I used the `cases` environment. Also from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Please can you put a MWE starting \documentclass? Thank you very much. PS: Put \ldots instead of .... like the user. +1

Comment: Oh, okay. I did it on Math.SE, by the way. That's why.

Answer (score 3):

The right tool is `align*`; with `cases*` provided by `mathtools` the input is vastly simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\Pi^n\alpha_1, \dots,\alpha_n) &=
    \begin{cases*}
      1 & per $\mathscr{I}(\langle \alpha_1, \dots,\alpha_n \rangle) \in  \mathscr{I}(\Pi^n)$
      \\
      0 & nei casi restanti
    \end{cases*}
  \\
  \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\lnot \varphi) &=
    \begin{cases*}
      1 & per $\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi)=0$
      \\
      0 & nei casi restanti
    \end{cases*}
  \\
  \mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi \land \psi) &=
    \begin{cases*}
      1 & per $\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\varphi) = 1$ e $\mathscr{V}_{\mathscr{M},g}(\psi)=1$
      \\
      0 & nei casi restanti
    \end{cases*}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I changed “SSE” into “per” because I can't stand the former.

[image]